# Constructing a grid date diagram

Tags: grid-layouts

How can I create a date diagram like that?

[image]

Let's say that the counting is done each couple of days, and the right bar represents the counting totals.

Comment: You can construct it using graphics primitives such as `Rectangle`.  What is the input data you would use to make the plot and what have you tried so far?  It is not difficult but it takes a bit of work, so it would be great if you could clarify where you got stuck and ask for more specific help ...

Comment: Or you might try ArrayPlot

Comment: Yes, ArrayPlot will be simpler but I think it won't make it possible to draw a frame only around some of the little rectangles.

Comment: clarifying the question, the totals can be simple countings, like this: day 1,2 = 130; day 3,4 = 400; day 5,6= 754; etc... Note that the max count 800 - right bar- could be any number since totals for couple of days could be 1230, 5.000 etc. Or we can stablish a upper limit based on the max totals of a certain day counting.

Comment: To simplify let's  assuming  countings for each day,  forget  couples days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind a few differences here and there, the biggest bang for the buck is `ArrayPlot`/`MatrixPlot`

Suppose you have you data in a nested list, gathered by month

```
ts[[1,1]] == (* jan/01 *)
ts[[2,20]] == (* feb/20 *)
(* and so on *)
```

You can plot them directly

```
MatrixPlot[ts, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"PlumColors", {0, 800}}], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameTicks -> {Thread@{Range[12], monthNames}, Range[2, 31, 2]},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Line[{{0, 12 - 3}, {31, 12 - 3}}]}]
```

> [image: Month]

If you spend some time with the options (`Mesh`, `FrameTicks`, `ColorFunction`) you might get a better approximation!

Comment: Interesting!  I didn't realize that MatrixPlot supported ragged arrays.  Unfortunately it doesn't show the raggedness in the mesh (`Mesh -> All`)

Comment: I must confess I was expecting it to fail at some point, but since it never did... The `Mesh` issue is why a chose a palette with `Black` as the zero color, since `White` is taken as "Null". It's not exactly the same, but I hope it's somehow useful!

Comment: Probably, a temperature color would be better?

Comment: Unfortunately, `ColorData["TemperatureMap"]` has `White` as the middle color, and `ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"]` does not work with the custom range option (a bug, perhaps).